# member.addRole(role.id).then(member => { ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a reaction role menu, and when I react this error comes up!

```
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.bot) return;
  const roleName = reaction.emoji.name;
  const role = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());
  const member = reaction.message.guild.members.find(member => member.id === user.id);
  member.addRole(role.id).then(member => {
    console.log("Am adaugat" + member.user.username + " la un rol!");
  })
})
```

Comment: The error shows that the role which you tried to find doesn't exist. Try logging the `roleName` variable and manually check whether or not there is a role with that name.

Answer (score 0):

It means your variable role is null.
try

```
const role = reaction && reaction.message && reaction.message.guild && reaction.message.guild && reaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());
```

i think either your variable is null or there's no object with the same rolename.